# Creating a column that returns max value based on group and max value

Tags: r

Hi i'm need to create a column in my data frame with the newest index for each Zip code. The newest index is based on **Year** and **Quarter**.

```
 A tibble: 51,053 x 4
      Year       Quarter   Zipcode  Indeks
      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     2020           3       2100   106.
 2     2020           3       1123   114.
 3     2020           3       1700   108.
 4     2020           3       1973   111.
 5     2020           3       2100   106.
 6     2020           3       2100   106.
 7     2020           3       2300   107.
 8     2020           3       2100   106.
 9     2020           3       2100   106.
10     2020           3       2300   107.
```

i have tried the following

```
Raw3<-Raw3 %>% 
  group_by(Zipcode) %>% 
  mutate(Indeks_max = max(Indeks)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

But i noticed that this gives me the max **index**, but i want the newest index that is based on max **Year** and **Quarter**

Comment: What do you mean by `I want the newest index that is based on max Year and Quarter` ? Can you show your expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Raw3 %>% 
  group_by(Zipcode) %>%
  mutate(Indeks_last = last(Indeks)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

In this case `dplyr::last` is the function you want to identify the last-appearing value of Indeks within each Zipcode.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nth.html

In case your data might not be in chronological order, you could add `arrange(Year, Quarter)` before the `mutate` line.

Comment: Mind to explain your solution?

Comment: it worked! i just added a order by in the last function.